# How can i get the junit aassert failure reason in teardown method of test

Tags: java, junit

I have written one simple test with setup,Test and tearwon method.In test i have writen 3 assert statements.First one is passed and second one is fail and third one is again pass.
Now i want to get the result of test in teardown whether it is pass or fail and If it is fail what was the reason.
Help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: If a test fails is will throw an AssertionException with the message.

Comment: Why do you want the reason? Doesn't running JUnit tell you when the assert fails?

Comment: Running the Junit tell me but i want to log it into file

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown Actually, assertion failures throw an [AssertionError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html), and Errors are *not* Exceptions

Comment: @Bohemian fine, whatever

Comment: Then direct the JUnit errors to your log file

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [TestWatcher rule](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html).

```
public static class YourTest {
  @Rule
  public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
      // log the AssertionError e
    }
  };

  @Test
  public void testSomething() {
    //your test
  }
}
```